# Getting error 'Insight.Database.FastExpando' does not contain a definition for 'Set1'

Tags: insight.database

The following code is giving the above error, and I cannot figure out why:

```
var x = _sqlConn.Connection().QueryResults<Results>("MyDb.dbo.get_records", new { id = theId });
int retVal = x.Outputs.Return_Value;

if (retVal == 0) // ...meaning result set was also returned...fine to this point.
{
    var list = x.Outputs.Set1;      // exception thrown here with above error
    var temp = list.FirstOrDefault();
```

I have been using other features of Insight.Database for a number of years, but have not had to retrieve a SQL RETURN value at the same time as a recordset.  The SQL itself works correctly in SSMS, returning a result set and the RETURN value of 0, as expected.  This is happening in VS2019, .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.2; Insight.Database 5.2.7 and 5.2.8.

I got this code from the following page:
https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/wiki/Specifying-Result-Structures
where it shows this:

```
var results = connection.QueryResults<Beer, Glass>("GetAllBeersAndAllGlasses");
IList<Beer> beers = results.Set1;
```

which I combined with the following code from here:
https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/wiki/Output-Parameters

```
var results = connection.QueryResults<Results>("MyProc", inputParameters);
var p = results.Outputs.p;
```

That part works.  It's accessing .Set1 that is failing, and I am not sure how to track down why.
I do not have experience with the FastExpando class, but Jon promised magic, and I want to believe.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tried results+dynamic objects in a while…

I think it is because you are doing:

`QueryResults<Results>` and Results is an Insight type

You probably want:

`QueryResults<MyType>`

And then you get back a `Results<MyType>`
Which contains the return val and Set1

If not, post a ticket over on github and we will help you out.

Comment: That gives a compile error; ticket posted at github with the original problem and the compile error.  Thank you.

Comment: Issue resolved over at github; thanks everyone.